# How to handle unexpected data from the post request body in NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, nestjs, backend

In NestJS official tutorial of validation. We can handle wrong data type from client side post request.

```
// dtos/CreateUserDto.ts

import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;
}
```

```
// controllers/user.controller.ts

@Post()
async createUser(@Body() body: CreateUserDto) {
 return body;
}
```

When I create a post request like

```
 curl -X POST 'http://domain/user' -d '{"email": "john", "password": "changeme"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I will get an expected error return.

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "email must be an email"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

my concern is an scenario that post request with unexpected data

```
 curl -X POST 'http://domain/user' -d '{"email": "john@example.com", "password": "changeme", "foo": "bar"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I will get a return.

```
{
"email": "john@example.com",
"password": "changeme",
"foo": "bar"
}
```

I suppose the key `foo` would be deleted or return a system error, but it doesn't do that.

What is the best way to handle this condition ?

Comment: Could you use a mapper? That is a service that you can write to convert any body to the expected CreateUserDto.

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is this: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#stripping-properties

Comment: @Moti Oh my eyes, why I miss document... 
thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since NestJS is using `class-validator` you can pass all the properties to the validation pipe that are supported by class-validator [options](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#passing-options).

```js
ValidatorOptions {
  skipMissingProperties?: boolean;
  whitelist?: boolean;
  forbidNonWhitelisted?: boolean;
  groups?: string[];
  dismissDefaultMessages?: boolean;
  validationError?: {
    target?: boolean;
    value?: boolean;
  };

  forbidUnknownValues?: boolean;
  stopAtFirstError?: boolean;
}
```

If you want not just strip values but throw an error when an unexpected value is passed you can use `forbidUnknownValues: true`.

Answer (score 0):

first install class-validator class-transformer

then configure this in main.ts and you can pass your validationoptions in ValidationPipe class such as whitelist?: true

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

this will automatically handle unexpected data globally across all the routes in your application